# How to sort strings alphabetically using compareTo() method?

Tags: java, methods, variable-assignment

I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while, but I am at a loss of what to do. I have to sort two different strings alphabetically using the compareTo() method, however, the compiler outputs "possible loss of precision", I am at a loss of what to do. Heres the code;

```
    String Word1;
    String Word2;

    char Compare;

    int Word1_Length = 0;
    int Word2_Length = 0;

    System.out.println("This event will require you to enter two words.");
    System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER THE FIRST WORD");

    Word1 = in.readLine();
    Word1_Length = Word1.length();
    System.out.println(Word1_Length);
    Word1_Letter0 = Word1.charAt(0);
    System.out.println(Word1_Letter0);

    System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER THE SECOND WORD");

    Word2 = in.readLine();
    Word2_Length = Word2.length();
    System.out.println(Word2_Length);
    Word2_Letter0 = Word2.charAt(0);
    System.out.println(Word2_Letter0);

    Compare = Word1.compareTo(Word2);

    System.out.println(Compare);
```

Comment: I cannot compile your code. In my Eclipse I get *Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char* on the line `Compare = Word1.compareTo(Word2);`. It’s a different symptom of the same problem that you are asking about.

Comment: What is `in`? What is `Word1_Letter0`? What is `Word2_Letter0`? --- Why do you believe the result of using [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) on two `String` objects (`Word1` and `Word2`) is a `char` value (`Compare`), when it is *documented* to return an `int`?

Comment: *FYI:* Java naming convention is for local variable names to start with lowercase letter, so it should be `word1`, `word2`, `compare`, `word1_Length `, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be easier for us to read your code (which you want us to do) if you follow the Java naming conventions. A variable name should begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: It's also Java convention to declare variables when (or as close to) when you first assign them. For example, `String Word1 = in.readLine(); int Word1_Length = Word1.length();`.

Comment: I guess the specific issue here is that `Word1.compareTo(Word2)` returns an `int`, but `Compare` is a `char`. Declare `Compare` as `int`.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I will change my variable naming convention as I have been doing what my teacher said, but evidently is wrong. I apologize for the issues with my conventions, I am very new to coding and appreciate the help. I changed compare from a char to an int and it compiled and ran, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`word1.compareTo(word2)` (after correcting your uppercase) returns an `int` (you can read this fact in the documentation, and most IDEs will also tell you).  `compare` is declared a `char`. You cannot assign an `int` to a `char`. And if you could, “loss of precision” would be a severe euphemism. An `int` is signed, and the sign of the result of `compareTo()` tells you the order of the two strings. A `char` if you perceive it as a number (which is already a misuse) is unsigned, it cannot hold a negative value. So you would be losing the information that you just queried.

As has been said in the comments, a solution is to declare `compare` an `int`:

```
   int compare = word1.compareTo(word2);
```

(now combining declaration and assignment, which usually helps readability.)

More advanced information: You can *cast* an `int` to a `char`, which is a conversion giving the mentioned *possible loss of precision*. It’s not what you want here, so I leave it by the mention. You can search for the term if you are curious.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will change my naming conventions (I had no clue something was wrong, as I mentioned in the comments my teacher requested uppercase), I guess my issue was a general ignorance to how the method functions.

Comment: (That’s funny. Possibly your teacher has coded C# or another language where uppercase is customary before.)

Comment: wowww amazing explanation 